# how to emit a message from browser when using Sails.io.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

Before I would just

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect(URL);
socket.emit("hello", {});
</script>
```

Using Sails.io.js, I tried `io.sails.emit("myevent", jsonData)` ... but can't do that:

```
io.socket.emit is not a function
```

So I do you actually emit a message to the websocket (from the browser) to the room you have joined?

What am I missing?

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no method `.emit()` in sails.socket.

You should use `.get()`, `.post()`, `.put()`, or `.delete()`.

**How to use it:**

instead of

```
socket.emit('eventName', jsonData)
```

now you use:

```
socket.get('routeToController', jsonData, callback);
```

**Example:**

You can create controller `SocketController.js`

```
module.exports = {
    myevent: function(req, res) {
        res.json({
            value: 1
        });
    }
};
```

in `config/routes.js` add:

```
'GET /socket/myevent': 'SocketController.myevent'
```

and now you can call:

```
socket.get('/socket/myevent', jsonData, function(error, data){
    //data = {value: 1}
});
```

Comment: only `emit` takes 2 params, `emit("event-name", json_data)`, I still don't how I can do